# Mars rover Kata. Can either turn or advance

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this kata in which I have a rover that I need to be able to give instructions to inside a board of 10x10. Rover can do only 1 movement at a time. Either turn or advance.

When I `console.log` the functions for advance I'm not getting the updated position of the rover on the board. I can't figure it out. I wrote everything and had found a solution but then I broke it overwriting something and can't figure out what I erased or changed.

```js
// Rover Object Goes Here
// ======================
let grid;
let rover = {
  direction: "N",
  location: {x:0,y:0},
  // path: [{x:0,y:0}]
}

// ======================

//Turn left function
function turnLeft(rover){
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case "N":
      rover.direction = "W";
      break;
    case "W":
      rover.direction = "S";
      break;
    case "S":
      rover.direction = "E";
      break;
    case "E":
      rover.direction = "N";
      break; 
  }   
  console.log(`turnLeft was called!. Rover is now facing ${rover.direction}` );    
}


//Turn right function
function turnRight(rover){
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case "N":
      rover.direction = "E";
      break;
    case "E":
      rover.direction = "S";
      break;
    case "S":
      rover.direction = "W";
      break;
    case "W":
      rover.direction = "N";
      break;      
  }   
  console.log(`turnRight was called!. Rover is now facing ${rover.direction}` );    
}


//  Function for moving rover
function moveForward(theRover) {
  //Variables
  let locationX = theRover.location.x;
  let locationY = theRover.location.y;
  let roverDir = theRover.direction;
  let roverInfoConsole = `Current rover position is x:${locationX} y:${locationY}
                Current rover direction is ${roverDir} `; 
  // Restricted Moves  
  if ( (roverDir === "N" && locationY <= 0) ||
      (roverDir === "E" && locationX >= 9) ||
      (roverDir === "S" && locationY >= 9) ||
      (roverDir === "W" && locationX <= 0)     ) {

    console.log(`Cannot move in that direction. The rover would move to a restricted area.
                ${roverInfoConsole}`);

  //allowed moves
    //North
   } else if (roverDir === "N" && locationY <= 9) {
      locationY = locationY - 1;
      console.log(`moveForward was called. 
                   Current rover position is x:${locationX} y:${locationY}
                Current rover direction is ${roverDir} `);
    //East
   } else if (roverDir === "E" && locationX < 9) {
      locationX = locationX + 1;      
      console.log(`Current rover position is x:${locationX} y:${locationY}
                Current rover direction is ${roverDir} `);
    //South
   } else if (roverDir === "S" && locationY  < 9) {
      locationY = locationY + 1;
      console.log(`moveForward was called. 
                   Current rover position is x:${locationX} y:${locationY}
                Current rover direction is ${roverDir} `);
    //West
   } else if (roverDir === "W" && locationX < 9) {
      locationX = locationX - 1;      
      console.log(`moveForward was called. 
                   Current rover position is x:${locationX} y:${locationY}
                Current rover direction is ${roverDir} `);
   }
};

console.log(turnRight(rover));
console.log(moveForward(rover));
console.log(moveForward(rover));
console.log(turnRight(rover))
console.log(moveForward(rover));
console.log(moveForward(rover));
```

I expected the ouput in the end to be:

```
"Current rover position is x:2 y:2
Current rover direction is S "
```

But it's not updating the position. This is the whole console log I actually get:

```
"turnRight was called!. Rover is now facing E"
undefined
"Current rover position is x:1 y:0
                Current rover direction is E "
undefined
"Current rover position is x:1 y:0
                Current rover direction is E "
undefined
"turnRight was called!. Rover is now facing S"
undefined
"moveForward was called. 
                   Current rover position is x:0 y:1
                Current rover direction is S "
undefined
"moveForward was called. 
                   Current rover position is x:0 y:1
                Current rover direction is S "
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things altering your results:

1) None of your functions return anything, so logging their output makes no sense. Removing that removes all the `undefined` entries in the log.

2) More importantly, in the moveForward function, you calculate the new location using the `LocationX` and `LocationY` variables, but you never update the rover object's location properties. So next time you run that function, the location values are take from the rover object again, and they are still the same as they were the previous time because they were never updated.

I have also removed some repetition/redundancy in your logging.

Working demo:

```js
// Rover Object Goes Here
// ======================
let grid;
let rover = {
  direction: "N",
  location: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  // path: [{x:0,y:0}]
}

// ======================

//Turn left function
function turnLeft(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case "N":
      rover.direction = "W";
      break;
    case "W":
      rover.direction = "S";
      break;
    case "S":
      rover.direction = "E";
      break;
    case "E":
      rover.direction = "N";
      break;
  }
  console.log(`turnLeft was called!. Rover is now facing ${rover.direction}`);
}


//Turn right function
function turnRight(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case "N":
      rover.direction = "E";
      break;
    case "E":
      rover.direction = "S";
      break;
    case "S":
      rover.direction = "W";
      break;
    case "W":
      rover.direction = "N";
      break;
  }
  console.log(`turnRight was called!. Rover is now facing ${rover.direction}`);
}


//  Function for moving rover
function moveForward(theRover) {
  //Variables
  let locationX = theRover.location.x;
  let locationY = theRover.location.y;
  let roverDir = theRover.direction;

// Restricted Moves  
  if ((roverDir === "N" && locationY <= 0) ||
    (roverDir === "E" && locationX >= 9) ||
    (roverDir === "S" && locationY >= 9) ||
    (roverDir === "W" && locationX <= 0)) {

    console.log(`Cannot move in that direction. The rover would move to a restricted area.
                ${roverInfoConsole}`);

    //allowed moves
    //North
  } else if (roverDir === "N" && locationY <= 9) {
    locationY = locationY - 1;
    //East
  } else if (roverDir === "E" && locationX < 9) {
    locationX = locationX + 1;
    //South
  } else if (roverDir === "S" && locationY < 9) {
    locationY = locationY + 1;
    //West
  } else if (roverDir === "W" && locationX < 9) {
    locationX = locationX - 1;
  }
  theRover.location.x = locationX;
  theRover.location.y = locationY;
  console.log(`moveForward was called. 
               Current rover position is x:${locationX} y:${locationY}
               Current rover direction is ${roverDir} `);
};

turnRight(rover);
moveForward(rover);
moveForward(rover);
turnRight(rover);
moveForward(rover);
moveForward(rover);
```

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the whole locationX and locationY variables. And instead used the plain theRover.location.x and theRover.location.y  throughout the whole code.  Also deleted the console.log as you showed when calling the functions and don't get any more undefined. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must increment/decrement `theRover.location.x` and `theRover.location.y` instead of the temporary variables you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the whole locationX and locationY variables. And instead used the plain theRover.location.x and theRover.location.y    Also deleted the console.log when calling the functions and don't get any more undefined. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help